# Extension of Fourier transform to complex analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f(x) \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ have compact support, say $\operatorname{supp}(f) = [-R,R]$. We have the Fourier transform

$$\hat{f}(\xi) := \int_{\Bbb{R}} e^{-ix\xi} f(x) dx = \int_{-R}^R e^{-ix \xi} f(x)dx .$$

I want to show that $\hat{f}(\xi)$ extends to a complex analytic function $F(z)$ defined by
$$F(z) := \int_{-R}^R e^{-ixz}f(x) dx.$$

That is, I need to show that 
$$F'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-R}^R \left( \frac{e^{-ixh} - 1}{h}\right)e^{-ixz}f(x) dx$$
exists. I want to do this using the dominated convergence theorem.

> > **My question is:** How can we bound the term $$ \frac{e^{-ixh} - 1}{h}$$ independently of $h$? Intuitively this is just the derivative of $e^{-ixz}$ at $0$ and so it is bounded. Can we make some sort of argument using Taylor's theorem by saying that for $h$ sufficiently small, (Say $h \in B(\epsilon,0)$), there is some $z_0 \in B(\epsilon,0)$ such that
> >     $$\left|\frac{e^{-ixh} - 1}{h}\right| \leq |e^{-ixz_0}| $$
> >     for all $h \in B(\epsilon,0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
    \left|\frac{e^{-ixh}-1}{h}\right|= \left|\left.\frac{1}{h}e^{-iyh}\right|_{y=0}^{y=x}\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{x}-ie^{-iyh}dy\right| \le |x|.
$$

Comment: I apologize for chiming in so late, but I believe there is an error in this solution. Since we want to show that $F$ is analytic as a function defined on $\mathbb C$, we need the estimate to hold as $h\to 0$ in the complex plane (not just on the real axis). For example, the estimate $$\left|\frac{e^{-ixh}-1}{h}\right|\leq|x|$$ fails in general if $h=i$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$M=\sup_{|z|\leq 1}\left\{\left|\frac{e^z-1}{z}\right|\right\}.$$ If $|h|\leq\frac{1}{R}$ (so that $|-ixh|\leq 1$), then $$\left|\frac{e^{-ixh}-1}{h}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{-ixh}-1}{-ixh}\right||x|\leq M|x|.$$